# What does the : infix operator do in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm reading [A Gentle Introduction to Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/index.html) (which is not so gentle) and it repeatedly uses the `:` operator without directly explaining what it does.

So, what exactly does it do?

Comment: It's not gentle at all. If this is your first contact with functional programming I recomend this site: http://learnyouahaskell.com/ 

After reading through this site then return to A Gentle Introduction. It really smooths the way a lot.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`:` is the “prepend” operator:

```
x : xs
```

Returns a list which has `x` as first element, followed by all elements in `xs`. In other functional languages, this is usually called `cons`, because it “cons”tructs a list recursively by repeated application from an empty list:

```
1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : []
```

is the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: how is this different than the `++` operator which concatenates lists?

Comment: @dlkulp `++` concatenates one list to another. With `:` the first argument is of type `a` (an arbitrary type) and the second argument is of type `[a]` which is the type of lists of elements of `a`.

Comment: Actually, "cons" comes from LISP - "In computer programming, cons (/ˈkɒnz/ or /ˈkɒns/) is a fundamental function in most dialects of the Lisp programming language. cons constructs memory objects which hold two values or pointers to values. These objects are referred to as (cons) cells, conses, non-atomic s-expressions ("NATSes"), or (cons) pairs."

Comment: @ChaosRules Yes that’s correct, but my answer didn’t say anything differently.

Comment: "cons"-tructor!  i'm getting old, man.  i couldn't quite figure out "why is the nickname 'cons'?"

Answer (score 25):

Could always check out the types in GHCi/HUGS, as the first steps in the tutorial encourage you to download GHC/HUGS.

```
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
Prelude> :t (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

From their respective types, it's quite easy to deduce their usage.

PS:  http://haskell.org/hoogle/ is awesome.

Comment: Why thank you sir!  If you download hoogle, you can use it as a function within ghc.  It's pretty sweet.  Allows you to search by type or function name without having to import, beats :t in every way.

Comment: Technically (:) could be x (:) xs = xs or x (:) xs = xs ++ [x]

Comment: I find `:i` to (sometimes) be a lot more informative than `:t`. `:i (:)` will give you `data [] a = ... | a : [a]`, and `:i []` will give you the complete list definition, `data [] a = [] | a : [a]`.

Comment: You can't find (:) on hoogle. Why not?

Answer (score 17):

The : operator in Haskell is the constructor for lists. It 'cons' whatever is before the colon onto the list specified after it.

For instance, a list of integers is made by 'consing' each number onto the empty list, e.g;

The list `[1,2,3,4]`
can be constructed as follows:

- `4 : []` (consing 4 to the empty list)
- `3 : [4]` (consing 3 onto the list containing 4)
- `2 : [3,4]` (consing 2 onto the list containing 3, 4)
- `1 : [2,3,4]` (consing 1 onto the list containing 2,3,4)

giving you;

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Written fully that's;

```
1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : []
```

Answer (score 12):

It is the type constructor for lists. It is no different from any other type constructor like `Just` or `Left`, except that it is infix. Valid type constructors can either be words starting with a capital letter, or symbols starting with a colon.

So you can define infix constructors for your own data types. For example:

```
data MyList a = a :> MyList a
              | Empty
```

in the above code we define a type called `MyList` with two constructors: the first is a weird-looking constructor `:>` which takes an element and another `MyList a`; the second is an empty constructor `Empty` which is equivalent to `[]` in Haskell's native lists.

The above is equivalent to :

```
data MyList a = Cons a  (MyList a)
              | Empty
```