# Haskell's infix operator for Javascript

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming

Is there an equivalent construct in Javascript. If not, how would you create one?

Here's a straightforward explanation of what the infix operator does in Haskell:

[What does the : infix operator do in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696751/what-does-the-infix-operator-do-in-haskell)

Comment: What are you trying to concatenate ?

Comment: The `(:)` operator is usually called the "cons operator", because it's by far not the only infix operator in Haskell (e.g. `+` is also an infix operator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have a list type, but it has `Array`s.

You can use...

```
var newArr = [val].concat(arr);
```

Alternatively, you could use `unshift()` to prepend to an array, but it mutates the original.

JavaScript doesn't have a `:` operator, operator overloading or methods that look like operators, so you can't get a similar syntax as Haskell.

Comment: Found this link which has an example of how you would emulate the infix operator: http://www.techtangents.com/emulating-infix-operator-syntax-in-javascript/

Comment: The link is dead, but the page is [in the archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20140610003932/http://www.techtangents.com/emulating-infix-operator-syntax-in-javascript/).

Answer (score 2):

I saw Leila Hamon already linked to [this article on emulating infix operators in JS](http://www.techtangents.com/emulating-infix-operator-syntax-in-javascript/).

But I thought an example may be useful to others.

Here is how you could hack the `Number` and `Boolean` prototypes to handle chained infix expressions such as `4 < 5 < 10`.

You could extend this further by applying more methods to more prototypes.  It is a little bit ugly but could be useful for making queries less verbose.

```
//Usage code
(4) .gt (6) .gt (4) //false

(100) .lt (200) .lt (400) . gt(0) . gt(-1)//true

(100) [ '>' ] (50) [ '<' ] (20)//false



//Setup Code
(function(){

  var lastVal = null;


  var nP = Number.prototype
  var bP = Boolean.prototype

  nP.gt = function(other){
    lastVal = other;
    return this > other;
  }

  nP.lt = function(other){
    lastVal = other;
    return this < other;
  }

  bP.gt = function(other){
    var result = lastVal > other;
    lastVal = other;
    return result;
  }

  bP.lt = function(other){
    var result = lastVal < other;
    lastVal = other;
    return result;
  }

  bP['<'] = bP.lt
  bP['>'] = bP.gt
  nP['<'] = nP.lt
  nP['>'] = nP.gt


})()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the prettiest, but it may help with readability in places where you want infix so your code reads like prose

```
function nfx(firstArg, fn, secondArg){
    return fn(firstArg, secondArg);
}

// Usage

function plus(firstArg, secondArg) {
    return firstArg + secondArg;
}

nfx(1, plus, 2);
```