# Haskell: subdividing a list into smaller groups based on a condition

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

When we give the function a condition and a list, it should group the elements together in a list until one doesn't meet the condition. Then it should make a new sublist until one meets the condition again, and so forth.

**Example:**

slice even [1,3,2,4,5,7,4,6] == [[],[1,3],[2,4],[5,7],[4,6]]

```
slice :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
slice _ [] = [[]]
slice a (x:y:xs)
  | (a x == True && a y == True) || (a x == False && a y == False) = [(x : y : slice a xs)]
  | a x == True && a y == False = [x] : [y : slice a xs]
  | a x == False && a y == True = [x] : [y : slice a xs]
```

Comment: You will need an extra basecase: `[x]`.

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting an error? Or the wrong output? For what input?

Comment: [Homework](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/90527), I take it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to compile your code, I get an error:

```
main.hs:4:80: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
      Expected type: [a]
        Actual type: [[a]]
    * In the second argument of `(:)', namely `slice a xs'
      In the second argument of `(:)', namely `y : slice a xs'
      In the expression: (x : y : slice a xs)
    * Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a] (bound at main.hs:3:14)
        y :: a (bound at main.hs:3:12)
        x :: a (bound at main.hs:3:10)
        a :: a -> Bool (bound at main.hs:3:7)
        slice :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]] (bound at main.hs:2:1)
  |
4 |   | (a x == True && a y == True) || (a x == False && a y == False) = [(x : y : slice a xs)]
  |                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^
exit status 1
```

For example, you cannot execute `4:[[6]]`. So I created a function `myadd :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]` that allows this.
To eliminate further errors, I used a thorough knowledge of the operator [`:`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696751/what-does-the-infix-operator-do-in-haskell).
After the first startup attempt, I was forced to add an extra exit rule: `slice _ [y] = [[y]]`.

The resulting function you designed and modified by me does not return the desired result.
It is necessary to modify it to return the desired output.

```
slice :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
slice _ [] = [[]]
slice _ [y] = [[y]]
slice a (x:y:xs)
  | (a x == True && a y == True) || (a x == False && a y == False) = myadd x (slice a (y:xs))
  | a x == True && a y == False = [x] : slice a (y:xs)
  | a x == False && a y == True = [x] : slice a (y:xs)
```

Output:

```
[[1,3],[2,4],[5,7],[4,6]]
```

I would solve the task as follows:

```
slice :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
slice a b = slice' a b False

slice' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool -> [[a]]
slice' _ [] _ = [[]]
slice' a (x:xs) b
 | a x == b = []:(slice' a (x:xs) (not b))
 | otherwise = myadd x (slice' a xs b)
```

Input:

```
[1,3,2,4,5,7,4,6]
```

Output:

```
[[],[1,3],[2,4],[5,7],[4,6]]
```

Addendum:

> > `myadd a (x:xs) = (a:x):xs`